# Angular 2+ Configurable Api backend endpoints

Tags: angular

I have created an Angular app and need to have a way to configure endpoints without recompile the application due to deployment requirements. I'm using webpack. 
Any Idea? I need something that could work similar to Asp.net web.config.
I've found some ideas but nothing straight.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try creating config.json file that will have your configuration settings, then you can change file content without recompiling app